# Getting the id of last inserted record

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to get the id of last inserted record in the Db. But i'm getting the error

```
      Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in Z:\www\CI4\application\models           \report_model.php on line 69
```

my model:

```
       function getLastInserted() {
$query ="SELECT $id as maxID from info where $id = LAST_INSERT_ID()"

return $query; //line 69
       }
```

my controller:

```
            function index()
    {           

    $id=$this->report_model->getLastInserted();
    $this->load->view('u_type1',$id);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are missing a `;` on line 67 after the last `"`.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you are using the CI database library, you can use `$this->db->insert_id()`.

```
function getLastInserted() {
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: thanks:)..one question $this->db->insert_id() only works with active records?

Comment: No, `$this->db->insert_id()` returns the LAST INSERT property of your table regardless of how you inserted that data. This command will provide the last inserted id no matter what method of insertion you used.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get last id without insert function

```
$this->db->select('id')->order_by('id','desc')->limit(1)->get('table_name')->row('id');
```